# Quick Verilog HDL Prompt (Beginner)

Tags: verilog, hdl

I am a beginner with Verilog HDL and trying to model a few modules from logic diagrams. If two wires are input into a NAND gate followed by another inverter afterwards, would that just be a AND gate in theory? Since the output wire desired is on the other side of the inverter. Would it be.

```
AND
    g1(F,A,B)
```

A and B being the inputs and F being the output.
Also, just for future knowledge, how would I implement an inverter using Verilog?

Answer (score 5):

To answer your first question, yes, a NAND gate followed by an inverter is *logically equivalent* to an AND gate.

On your second question, the normal way to invert a signal in Verilog would be to use the bit-wise negation operator: `~`

```
wire A;
assign A = ~B;  // A is "not B"
```

Since you are asking about modeling simple logic using Verilog gate primitives, I will add that there is a primitive for an inverter called `not`.

```
not U1(A, B);  // A is "not B"
```

[Here](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/gate1.html) is a good reference on Verilog gate primitives.